# How to remove notification for suggested friend on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

How to remove notification for suggested friend on Facebook?
Example: do you know John? You can add him as your friend. It's giving me notification on the person that I do not know.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

One trick I use is simply to block that user.

Click on the suggested person, that gives you their home page.

Click on the three-dot icon below their picture, a dropdown menu appears.

In this dropdown is the option *Block User*.  Block them, Facebook stops offering that person as a friend.

It is however bit of a pain to block dozens of users.  Don't forget that Facebook will just offer you someone else instead and you may not know them either.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question. OP is asking _how to remove notification_, so if you block someone, Facebook will suggest a new person and you will get again a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Long press on the notification. There will be options to "Disable this type of notifications". Or click on the triple dot at the right side.